# Putting a smooth curve inside of a tube

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is a good way to draw a smooth curve with specified starting and ending point and restricted to be inside of a piecewise linear tube like below?

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/so-tubes.png))</sub>

```
coords = {1 -> {0, 2}, 2 -> {1/3, 1}, 3 -> {0, 0}, 
   4 -> {(1/3 + 2)/2, 1}, 5 -> {2, 1}, 6 -> {2 + 1/3, 0}, 
   7 -> {2 + 1/3, 2}};
gp = GraphPlot[graph, VertexCoordinateRules -> coords];
pr = {{-1, 3 + 1/3}, {-1 - 1/6, 3 + 1/6}};
scale = 50;
is = -scale*(Subtract @@@ pr);
lineThickness = 2/3;
graph = {1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 5 -> 7};
path = {3, 2, 4, 5, 7};
lp = Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[.5], 
    AbsoluteThickness[lineThickness*scale], Line[path /. coords]}];
Show[lp, gp, PlotRange -> pr, ImageSize -> is]
```

Comment: Would you accept a solution which drew a piecewise linear tube around a smooth curve ?

Comment: The goal is automatically constructed diagrams like first one here (ie, the colored curved lines inside the graph) -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
coords = {2 -> {1/3, 1}, 1 -> {0, 0}, 3 -> {(1/3 + 2)/2, 1}, 
   4 -> {2, 1}, 5 -> {2 + 1/3, 2}};
pr = {{-1, 3 + 1/3}, {-1 - 1/6, 3 + 1/6}};
scale = 50;
is = -scale*(Subtract @@@ pr);
lineThickness = 2/3;
graph = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5};
gp = GraphPlot[graph, VertexCoordinateRules -> coords];
path = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

f = BezierFunction[
   SortBy[coords /. Rule[x_, List[a_, b_]] -> List[a, b], First]];
pp = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}];

lp = Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[.5], 
    AbsoluteThickness[lineThickness*scale], Line[path /. coords]}];
Show[pp, lp, gp, PlotRange -> pr, ImageSize -> is]
```

[image]

You may gain a better control over the path by adding/removing control points for the Bezier. As I remember "A Bspline is contained in the convex hull of its control points", so you can add control points inside your thick lines (up and down the middlepoints in actual point set, for example) to bound the Bezier more and more.

**Edit**

The following is a first try to bound the curve. Bad programming, just to get the feeling of what can be done:

```
coords = {2 -> {1/3, 1}, 1 -> {0, 0}, 3 -> {(1/3 + 2)/2, 1}, 
   4 -> {2, 1}, 5 -> {2 + 1/3, 2}};
pr = {{-1, 3 + 1/3}, {-1 - 1/6, 3 + 1/6}};
scale = 50;
is = -scale*(Subtract @@@ pr);
lineThickness = 2/3;
graph = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5};
gp = GraphPlot[graph, VertexCoordinateRules -> coords];
path = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

kk = SortBy[coords /. Rule[x_, List[y_, z_]] -> List[y, z], 
  First]; f = BezierFunction[kk];
pp = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False];

mp = Table[{a = (kk[[i + 1, 1]] - kk[[i, 1]])/2 + kk[[i, 1]],
    Interpolation[{kk[[i]], kk[[i + 1]]}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][
      a] + lineThickness/2}, {i, 1, Length[kk] - 1}];
mp2 = mp /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y - lineThickness};
kk1 = SortBy[Union[kk, mp, mp2], First]
g = BezierFunction[kk1];
pp2 = ParametricPlot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False];

lp = Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[.5], 
    AbsoluteThickness[lineThickness*scale], Line[path /. coords]}];
Show[pp, pp2, lp, gp, PlotRange -> pr, ImageSize -> is]
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

Or perhaps better yet:

```
g1 = Graphics[BSplineCurve[kk1]]; 
Show[lp, g1, PlotRange -> pr, ImageSize -> is]
```

[image]

This one scales quite well when you enlarge the image (the previous ones don't)

Comment: Nice plots, I like the first ones better because it approximates the real life drawing constraints (you want to draw it as straight as possible without leaving the tube or having sharp corners), scaling isn't really an issue because I can change AbsoluteThickness to "Thickness"